# Python 3 if-else short-hand command syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

Python 3 is showing syntax error whenever I write `sys.exit() if condition else return`.

Why is this a syntax error?
If it can't be fixed is there any way to do the same operation in one line?

Comment: Because `x if condition else y` is an assignment shorthand. You cannot assign `return` keyword. Why do you want to do this in one line?

Comment: Is the "if" condition in a declared function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return` is a *statement* keyword that can't be used in an `x if y else z` *expression*.

Due to `sys.exit()` never actually returning (since it internally raises a `SystemExit` exception) and `None` being the implicit return value if you do `return` , you *could* do

```
return sys.exit() if condition else None
```

but that's hard to understand and you shouldn't strive to do things in one line for the sake of doing them in one line.

```
if condition:
    sys.exit()
return
```

is that much more readable.

Comment: *pass* can also be used instead of *None*, right?

Comment: @CoolCoder No, `pass` is not valid as a part of an expression. It's a statement like `return`.